# AbortPipeline() in GlassMapper 4.3.0.280?

Tags: glass-mapper

In Sitecore 8.1 with an older version of GlassMapper, I had implemented the following code to implement Patial Language Fallback:

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/elizabeth_spranzani/posts/partial-language-fallback-and-glass-mapper-v3

I am now upgrading to Sitecore 8.2 Update 1 and GlassMapper 4.3.

I am attempting to refactor the code for the changes to pipeline in GlassMapper 4.3.

Before we had some logic similar to the following:

```
if (scContext.Item == null)
{
    args.AbortPipeline();
    return;
}
```

It appears that AbortPipeline is no longer available.

Is it no longer needed due to the change in the way pipelines are handled or is there another method?

Comment: Just a thought and no answer to your question, but why write your own language fallback? Is the one available in the Sitecore box not sufficient?

Comment: Well maybe it isn't anymore.   We have had it in place since 8.0.   So maybe there have been changes so the partial language fallback isn't needed anymore.   Can anyone definitively answer?

Comment: i can see "Any tasks that you have already created pre version 4.3 will need to be updated to work with this approach", this means you have to refactor all your custom pipeline which were using 'AbortPipelie' in your earlier versions :( It could be a tedious process of migrating to 8.2 + GlassMapper 4.3 with these known breaking changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have refactored the way pipelines work in the 4.3.

Quote from the release notes:

> Normally you can just override the **Execute** method and when you are ready to call the next task in the pipeline you simple call **base.Execute**
>
> Any tasks that you have already created pre version 4.3 will need to
>   be updated to work with this approach.

So basically, you have to call **base.Execute** every time you want to continue the pipeline.

This means that in order to abort it you just don't call the **base.Execute**.

You can check the release notes here
http://www.glass.lu/Blog/Release4-3

Comment: "This means that in order to abort it you just don't call the base.Execute."  That was the part I wasn't sure of.    Thanks.